# Formatting problems (image size, alignment etc)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript

```
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        results.html(results.html() + "<div class='resultsImages'><img src='res/" + data[i]["imageURL"] + "'/></div>");
        results.html(results.html() + "<div class='resultsInfo'><h1>" + capitalizeThis(data[i]["title"]) + '</h1></div><br><br>');
    }

    #results>div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

CSS

```
.resultsImages {
    width: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
}
```

The image size is way bigger than it should be, and the text corresponding to the image shows up over the image. Also, there seem to be no breaks between the divs. Suggestions?
Any other suggestions about the code would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a starting point in code via a JSFiddle or CodePen, see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties to restrict the size of your images. The break between the `div`s is normal because by default a `div` has its `display` property set to `block` but you can change that by setting it to `inline-block`

```
.resultsImages{
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.resultsInfo{
    display: inline-block;
}
```